# send video over http (HTTP multipart request?)

Tags: http, video, multipart

Is there any way sending video (binary data) over HTTP?
I read that HTTP multipart request is used for that.

The problem is that when the client starts sending the clip, it doesn't have the entire video yet (still been captured by the camera). The client sends frame by frame.

Does multipart request is good for sending video before all clip is available?

Thanks.

Comment: What codec (Eg. H264, mjpeg, etc)?

Comment: Not sure yet. Probably it will be transferred for every video frame.

Comment: You really need to figure this out first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a streamable container format. The most popular today are Apples HTTP Live Streaming, and fragmented mp4 (usually called DASH)

Comment: The problem is that my client is an embedded device written in C and the server is written in C#. Does Apples HTTP Live Streaming in open to the public? Can it be easily ported to C# and C?

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: Does it open to public?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem sending binary data over HTTP, and no, you don't need multipart formats for that.

Comment: Does HTTP contains more overhead then TCP when sending data? Sending video clip over TCP is already risky (not real-time protocol).

Comment: HTTP uses TCP. The overhead for large data is minimal (header fields + potentially chunked encoding).